# Okay anyone know how to get GIMP working on a Ubuntu Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberrypi

I wish to get GIMP as well as Krita working on my new RaspPi4. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: GIMP works for me. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1299886/edit) to clearly explain the problem that you are encountering.

Comment: Okay, I found out what the problem. It was due to that I had an improperly installed Brave Browser.